# Find previous class anywhere on page with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to find the previous class `.parent-row` on click of `.add-image`

Following is the HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="row parent-row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Exercise Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[img][0][]" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-info small add-extra"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Exercise</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Exercise Image</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="data[vid][0][]" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-info small add-image"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Image</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Exercise Video</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[Exercise][name][]" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-info small add-video"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Video</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
$('html').on('click', '.add-image', function () {    
$(this).prevUntil('.parent-row');
$(this).prev('.parent-row');
$(this).closest('.parent-row');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.add-image` is previous sibling of closest div `.row`. you need to traverse to `.row` element and then use `.prev()` to target required div with class `.add-image`:

```
$(this).closest('.row').prev()
```

Answer (score 1):

The relationships you are using are wrong. The `parent-row` is a previous sibling of the `row` ancestor of the button, or both of the belongs to the same form

```
$('html').on('click', '.add-image', function () {
    $(this).closest('.row').prevAll('.parent-row').first();
    $(this).closest('form').find('.parent-row');
});
```